# LS2208 barcode scanner

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, webapps, scanner, barcode

I have a computer running Lubuntu 14.04 with a Symbol LS2208 barcode scanner attached. It scans fine most of the time, but has an irregular problem scanning codabar barcodes in web apps. It will sometimes randomly leave out one number in the middle of the barcode string. It is not always the same position, and the same barcode can sometimes work and sometimes not. The problem only occurs on my Lubuntu computer, not on my Windows computer. The problem happens when I scan barcodes into a variety of dialog boxes in a web browser (not all the same webapp). The problem seems to be specific to the machine and/or OS, not to a specific webapp. Any hints on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I can confirm: after upgrading machines to Lubuntu 14.04 I noticed that barcode reader started to make errors on reading.  Symptoms like OP describes.

Comment: Maybe you can configure your barcode scanner? There must be some doc. Raise the delay between the transmission of the characters, it might help.

Comment: @davidbaumann it may help, but I have 4-5 different barcode readers and all are affected. Still, I noticed, that Firefox is more problematic than Chromium. So maybe it is problem of newer Firefox.  It would be good to know, which browser OP used.